# Thermal management of high power MOSFETS

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, thermal

I am intending to build a PWM solar battery charger with 80-160A, for which I have already asked another [more general question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/658066/102846). Most of the possible [candidates](https://www.digikey.de/de/products/filter/transistoren/fets-mosfets/einzelne-fets-mosfets/278?s=N4IgjCBcoGwAwyqAxlAZgQwDYGcCmANCAPZQDaIAzAOwAcAnIyALpEAOALlCAMocBOASwB2AcxABfIvFpIQqSJlyES5cHACs1aoiJhN26iD0IATHFkmYlehCsaALHfUwYtDcZe1az-dThMJtQOCJ5%2BWr76WkZ6UXSe1DbUYA6eME7WpmH67qmxYCmRYKb%2B2SkwRQ4wWfmJcNnmJdkODjTNrZYg6WDWlO2U9bEO9LQ14GAalNWeDrTaGmMFGq5541oV2T76M3PBuuO0s-SbtJR9eiGmTRdwppS%2Bl6bODhpzd2FOE8dEs9puHylbgDaOkPo0HhoJvtutZVlVbCMPtEPBdtFU0hlKCjwLMeuccYdtAlTDBEjFwBoDIMKQUfGFJpQXgkJtRKfSQhsiJSsdRvhS3JCZm5TPRsTDKJ0oYdVtQnjpOrLSVMwvB7nD6K5pkREhUwPievowOSenc4PjZUbZSqSj0VQN4CqWgEdn99j1KQwEnBtJ69KSEKtIXAENSwKMcmFw6EfrsHMbchpsWH4LzI4kUmkNQhnDC45HGCL8yNJfQRWA%2BeWtBKMT0WmERuYS6dSZ4nvdkjX0vinr1nHKUqs3FVaNSnt5bK2Se5sVcYPRGa2XpSxqYqnHu3HV3zTImR9TklpBUQScsNa3bDBlp5DiP9WGzVlWCBONw%2BEIxJJpMU5AolPgiKQkAUAerJjC8Q47Bo9DUrMUFgT40EYmavogJSRr4mhOieAsoqdDh1jYSKiSETugaOJo2HkXhrKithOhmnRKbEqSrTYW4RrYfOWicVifJQVM2L8f8X7etSFTetCOSDqYozYku9ppE8DiLEO2x%2Boc5YqocTRPi%2BkC8AIIjiFI4AjMc0DyOg2D-qoQEgPUzAmeY-wWXpIAAKrCIIHAAPJoAAsngGA4AArvweCeCF3AAGqeAAtiI3Ajp%2BIAALRZBZCgCCFKiARQHiOSZiAWYIAAm3CpYanhuZ4HAAJ5sBF%2BnBagEgSEAA) for the output MOSFET look a little fairylike to me, especially with respect to the thin terminals, except [this](https://www.digikey.de/de/products/detail/ixys/VMO1200-01F/2117560) one, which looks a little more robust (also the most expensive, but that is of course not prohibitive if it is the right tool for the job). I wonder how to mount those little snowflakes so as to ensure proper thermal management as well as load capacity at said amperage. I just can't imagine that they are usually soldered to normal PCB traces at 160A or beyond...

I have chosen my cables from the PV as 50mm2 (and they still get hand-warm at the nominal current!), which I also naively expect from the mounting neighborhood of the MOSFET, as a rule of thumb. Since I am a hobbyist, I ask myself if it is probably unprofessional to solder the MOSFET directly to thick copper bars, for thermal and current management.

Comment: Did you actually look at the package and pin out? How are you going to connect the correct pins to the bus bar and only the bus bar and connects the other pins elsewhere? Surface mount packages are out completely and even through-hole with 3 large pins is going to be frustrating. There are MOSFET packages that are meant to be bolted to a heatsink with screw terminals for the wires, rather than on a printed circuit board. If you are going to solder to a copper bus bar you might as well go with a screw mount MOSFET.

Comment: I would have expected screw-mount also. But I have no clue why DigiKey responds with mostly SMD parts to my search/spec. I guess if DigiKey doesn't have screw-mount types, others won't either, no? (I haven't checked, but as a private person I am rather limited as to the suppliers anyway (e.g. Mouser is already difficult, at least in my country).

Comment: Well SMD is much more common. But they are on Mouser and Digikey. You probably just don't recognize the package name. It helps to filter by mounting method and current and look at the pictures. You will eventually run into them. I can't remember the name of any off the top of my head.

Comment: "Fairylike"? "Snowflakes"? Semiconductors have impressive capabilities these days; they are also very easy to misuse. You would do well to approach all the same projects but at much lower power levels. 12V 1A is a good ballpark for starting out. Learn all the dynamics of switching circuits and control theory first, and then scale up incrementally (say 2-4x per step) until you reach full scale.

Comment: Note that Mouser not all Mouser parts are properly classified. If you search MOSFET and filter by screw mount only a few results come up but it shows you some of the packages. If you then type in the package name into the search, many more results will come up. SOT-227 is one.

Comment: @DKNguyen: the point is - if I haven't filtered by package yet, but only by electrical spec, and I only get 19 results (of which none has the desired package), then I don't see how adding another filter can get me to the target...

Comment: @oliver Those screw mount packages are designed for *much* more amps than 80-160A. However, they are easier to mount and manage thermals with no PCB so you may want to work with them anyways. It certainly makes thermal management easier since they are oversized current capability and the mounting allows for better thermals. However, this comes at the expense of switching parasitics which you would need to look into. By the way, I don't pay attention to the rated current for MOSFET.s It's number obtained under imaginary conditions. Calculate the heat instead based on the datasheet.

Comment: @DKNguyen: that sounds very convincing. I have looked at Mouser, and found some types (not plenty). Most of them have prohibitive RDS(on). But that one looks nice: https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/IXYS/IXFN400N15X3?qs=uwxL4vQweFNnNYnwPv%2FzkA%3D%3D Are switching parasitics only important for losses, or for EMC also?

Comment: Ah, and now I know what was the problem with my DigiKey search: I only searched for in-stock items... ;-)

Comment: First, calculate how much power the MOSFET actually dissipates. Many of them have very impressively low on-resistance, so the power dissipation *can* be very low even with seemingly high currents. (but make sure to give the gate a high enough voltage to turn it fully on, and make sure to apply that voltage quickly and not linger half-on)

Comment: you can solder them to PCB traces; remembering that the limiting factor is heat, it's generally okay to have a *small* narrow part of the track as long as the rest of the part is wide enough as this helps the heat from the narrow part spread out and dissipate.

Comment: @oliver Parasitics can cause things like ringing and latchups. So both EMC and malfunctions.

Comment: Google thermal management of TO-263 packages <-- Texas Instruments have a decent document and probably there are others as well. It's all about thermal vias, multilayer PCBs, decent thickness of copper plating and good surface area.